# Использовать переменную из одной функции в другой

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def child_window():
    child_win = Toplevel()
    child_win.geometry("700x500")
    child_win.resizable(False, False)
    message_to = Label(child_win, text="Кому").place(x=10, y=13)
    message_subject = Label(child_win, text="Тема").place(x=10, y=43)
    message_text = Label(child_win, text="Текст").place(x=10, y=75)
    from_id = Entry(child_win, width=80)
    from_id.place(x=50, y=15)
    subject = Entry(child_win, width=80).place(x=50, y=45)
    main_message = Text(child_win, height=20, width=60).place(x=50, y=80)
    b1 = Button(child_win, text="Отправить", command=send_message1).place(x=50, y=420)


def send_message1():
    print()
```

Мне нужно использовать данные ( переменные ) из функции `child_window()` в функции `send_message1()`, как это можно сделать? Искал не подошли мне некоторые варианты, если можно то `from_id = Entry(child_win, width=80)` на этом примере

Comment: Через глобальную переменную. Или оформить функции в один класс и через переменную класса.

Comment: Через глобалную пробовал не получается, а как это можно оформит через класс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Передать через аргументы, используя `lambda`.
2. `.place` возвращает `None`, поэтому делайте не так: `var = Widget().place(x, y)`, а так:

```
var = Widget()
var.place(x, y)
```

```py
def child_window():
    child_win = Toplevel()
    child_win.geometry("700x500")
    child_win.resizable(False, False)
    message_to = Label(child_win, text="Кому")
    message_to.place(x=10, y=13)
    message_subject = Label(child_win, text="Тема")
    message_subject.place(x=10, y=43)
    message_text = Label(child_win, text="Текст")
    message_text.place(x=10, y=75)
    from_id = Entry(child_win, width=80)
    from_id.place(x=50, y=15)
    subject = Entry(child_win, width=80)
    subject.place(x=50, y=45)
    main_message = Text(child_win, height=20, width=60)
    main_message.place(x=50, y=80)
    b1 = Button(child_win, text="Отправить", command=lambda: send_message1(from_id))
    b1.place(x=50, y=420)


def send_message1(from_id):
    print(from_id)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло)))

Answer (score 0):

Можно передать через аргумент функции.

```
from functools import partial

def child_window():
    ...
    b1 = Button(child_win, text="Отправить", command=partial(send_message1,from_id)).place(x=50, y=420)

...
def send_message1(from_id):
    print(from_id.get())
```

---

Или использовать глобальную переменную.

```
def child_window():
    global from_id
    ...
    from_id = Entry(child_win, width=80)
    ...
    b1 = Button(child_win, text="Отправить", command=send_message1).place(x=50, y=420)


def send_message1():
    print(from_id.get())
```

---

Или оформить всё в класс.

```
class MyClass:
    def child_window(self):
        ...
        self.from_id = Entry(child_win, width=80)
        self.from_id.place(x=50, y=15)
        ...
        b1 = Button(child_win, text="Отправить", command=self.send_message1).place(x=50, y=420)


    def send_message1(self):
        print(self.from_id.get())
my = MyClass()
my.child_window()
```

Comment: А что это за библеотека? Она обязателна? Просто она у меня не устанавливается почему то

Comment: А я её и не устанавливал. Она часть Питона. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

Comment: Она у меня почему то не исползуется

Comment: Что у вас за питон? Этот модуль даже во втором питоне есть.

Comment: 3,8 вроде версия

Comment: Проверил на версиях Питона 2.7.17, 3.4.10, 3.6.3, 3.7.4, 3.8.2, 3.9.1. Под Linux и Windows. Везде есть эта библиотека. Увы, других питонов я у себя под рукой не нашёл.